# guessing game 0-100 java

Tags: java, max, min

I have a code I need to set from 0-100 and have it be a possibility to have zero be the right answer. I have set my Final ints to MAX(100)/MIN(0). But 0 is never the right answer. I'm 4 years into coding with 2 years experience in Java, but it seems that any problem 1-100 or 1- any other MAX is fine. Please help, or explain if 0 isn't an allowed selection.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        int MIN = 0;
        int MAX = 100;
        int answer;
        int guess;
        String another = "y";
        boolean flag = false;
        boolean anotherFlag = true;

        while(anotherFlag){
            answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;

            System.out.println("I'm thinkin of a number between 0 and " + MAX );
            System.out.println("Can you guess what it is? \n");
            flag = false;
            while(!flag) {
                guess = scan.nextInt();

                if(guess == answer){
                    System.out.println("You guessed correctly");
                    flag = true;

                } else{
                    System.out.println("That was wrong, try again.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Want to Play again?(y/n)");
            another = scan.next();

            if(another.equalsIgnoreCase("y") == true){
                anotherFlag = true;
            } else{
                anotherFlag = false;
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer is in answer

Comment: vaugness aside, I do aprreciate your help. but is it casue answer is set as an int, answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;......what?

Comment: `public int nextInt(int bound)`
Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Comment: You have the `+1` in the wrong place. Your current code returns a random number between 1-100. Instead, you need to move the `+1` here: `            answer = generator.nextInt(MAX + 1);` That will return a number between 0-100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with

```
    answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
```

Your answer range is  1 - MAX.

if you want to generate a random number between 0 - MAX, where MAX = 100. You should write-

```
    answer = generator.nextInt(MAX+1);
```

Because as per Java API (java v8),

```
    public int nextInt(int bound)
```

returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Comment: Thank you these IDE updates are for the birds lol. Again thank you for the help. It works perfect now!

Comment: I agree. Glad I could help.